# Why does useState() duplicate websocket events?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

My react component is receiving messages from a server via a websocket. When I try to update state using useState() the sockets get duplicated.

If I do this...

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default () => {

    let[message, setMessage] = useState()

    let ws = new WebSocket("ws://blah");

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        let obj = JSON.parse(e.data);

        // event name
        console.log(obj.event);

        // event data
        console.log(obj.value);

        // setMessage(obj.value)

        ws.close
    }
    return <div>
            {message}

    </div>
}
```

Then the console shows each message on its own as expected

But if I comment back in `setMessage(object.value)` then all the connections are duplicated for every message

Somehow the setMessage() causes connections to be accumulated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're are creating a new websocket on every render.

Since connecting to a web socket is a "side effect" you'll want to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default () => {

  let [message, setMessage] = useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let ws = new WebSocket("ws://blah");

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      let obj = JSON.parse(e.data);

      // event name
      console.log(obj.event);

      // event data
      console.log(obj.value);

      setMessage(obj.value);
    };

    return () => {
      ws.close()
    }
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      {message}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Galupuf that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @Galupuf that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just move the websocket declaration **out of the function**. This way, you can use it anywhere besides the `useEffect`:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from 'websocket';

const ws = new W3CWebSocket("ws://blah");

export default () => {

  let [message, setMessage] = useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      //...
      setMessage(obj.value);
    };

    return () => {
      ws.close()
    };
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      {message}
    </div>
  );
};
```